# Using a variable to get a key from an array

Tags: angularjs, object, ionic2

```
makeList(){
    this.list = Object.keys(this.soa);

    this.list.forEach(key => {
        this.soa.value.push(this.soa.key)

    });
    console.log(this.list);
    console.log(this.soa.value);


}
```

The Object soa would look like this :

```
{soaNaam:"Syfilis", soaTijd:"Test 2",soaSymp : "Symptomen",soaDia : "Diagnostiek",soaBeh: "Behandeling",soaNa : "Nacontrole",soaPar : "Partnerwaarschuwing"}
```

To give some context im trying to push the value of every key into an array in the object soa

I need this for an *NgFor, if someone knows a way to display it with the functionallity already in ngRepeat great !

EDIT: i meant *NgFor not repeat , so sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [];
function keyList(obj)
{

    for(key in obj)
    {
      arr.push(key)
    }
    return arr
}
keyList({soaNaam:"Syfilis", soaTijd:"Test 2",soaSymp : "Symptomen",soaDia : "Diagnostiek",soaBeh: "Behandeling",soaNa : "Nacontrole",soaPar : "Partnerwaarschuwing"})
```

Look like this?